# C# CopyFromScreen Problems

Tags: c#, performance, screenshot, dwm

for starters, i know there are already threads about this, but i cannot seem to find an answer which fits my needs and after about 4 months of research i have decided to ask a question here.

For a project i need to make screenshots cyclical. These screenshots are made based on the user parameters whether to use a display or not or the area the screenshot is taken from. (This means that it could be that the screenshot is only made from the half of the display or so.)

The thing is, its slow...
Yes i know, if i want to do it faster i have to use this library or that directx and so on.
But: Neither do i know directx, nor i could find an opensource lirary that is capable of returning a bitmap-data-stripe (and realy is faster).
Also i have tried out some tutorials for making screenshots with directx but wasn't able to get it to run properly.

About the performance thing, when using only 1 display, the performance isn't actually that bad. (Taking a screenshot is about 40ms for 1440p resolution)

The realy bad thing is DWM. (I guess its dwm).
When making screenshots everything acts normaly except when draging around windows. Like, watching a video on youtube is fine. But when i start to move around windows, its slow as hell. Is seems that the draging animation is blocked while i take a screenshot.

Now for to my question (or questions):

- Someone does know this behavior and/or has an solution?
- What are my alternatives (serious alternatives. i mean like 3x 1440p in 30ms alternatives)

Edit: This is the method i use to make screenshots

```
public void makeScreenshot(int i)
{
    if (DisplayList[i].UseDisplay)
    {
        // copy from screen into graphics
        this.graphicsList[i].CopyFromScreen(Screen.AllScreens[DisplayList[i].DisplayNo].Bounds.X, AreaTop[i], 0, 0, sizeList[i], CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
        // bitmapData is filled with LockBits from Screenshotted Bmp
        bitmapData[i] = this.bitmapList[i].LockBits(rect[i], ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        // Pointer set to first pixel of Bitmap data
        Iptr[i] = bitmapData[i].Scan0;
        // Now Marshalcopy bitmapData to Pixel Array
        Marshal.Copy(Iptr[i], Pixels[i], 0, Pixels[i].Length);
        // Finaly unlock bits of Bitmap for next run
        this.bitmapList[i].UnlockBits(bitmapData[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code example?  Are you using a library like a screen recorder library?

Comment: attatched it to the main post

Comment: You've already said you aren't going to bother with the alternatives so why ask?

Comment: @JoePhilllips i didn't say i wont try out anything else. i said that i didn't found any serious alternative. i won't mind to try out some librarys or directx tutorials on this, if someone knows a good one.

Comment: Slamming DWM as hard as you possibly can is just not a good strategy, you *will* notice.  Commercial screen recorders use black moochoo art, they don't share their secrets with anyone.  Buy, don't build.

Comment: I would guess that the "blocking" comes from your LockBits and UnlockBits methoids preventing other code from affecting the monitor's current bitmap. I would presume that most screenshot libraries ask for a reference to the last swap buffer to be preserved in some way, while it's copied out to a file, instead of lock the current visuals. I would also presume that at a certain frequency of screenshots, it makes more sense to encode a video to reduce drive write strain. So, yeah, there are a number of problems to resolve.

Comment: @Katana314 LockBits locks the bitmapdata within the bitmap. The data within the bitmap is not a reference, it is copied from a buffer with the CopyFromScreen method. So whats blocking is CopyFromScreen. But also it does't not lock the whole screen, it just locks dmw.

Comment: What is your OS requirement. Is Windows 8 or higher ok?

Comment: @SimonMourier It should work with 7,8 and 10

Comment: Windows 8 has a very interesting low-level technology called Desktop Duplication API. Before that, I would follow Hans' advice.

Answer (score 4):

There is a quite simple and stable solution I've used for screen capturing and live streaming, but it do use an external library. May be you can spend several minutes to look at this. I got 6-15ms for 1600x900 screen capture.
So, u need -

1. Mirage Driver, that you can get here:
   http://www.demoforge.com/dfmirage.htm
2. this sample application:
   http://www.demoforge.com/sdk/MirrSharp.zip

I have modified the code for the sample solution to display the screen in PictureBox control every time the desktop changed event is fired. Something like this:

```
private void _mirror_DesktopChange(object sender, DesktopMirror.DesktopChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Changed rect is {0},{1} ; {2}, {3} ({4})", new object[] { e.x1, e.y1, e.x2, e.y2, e.type }));

        var perf = new Stopwatch();
        perf.Start();
        var bitmap = _mirror.GetScreen();
        perf.Stop();

        label1.Invoke(new Action<Int64>(i =>
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
            label1.Text = i.ToString();
        }), perf.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
```

Comment: This is a great thing. Have been playing around with it for the last half hour. I would love to use it but unfortunately it doesn't work properly with windows 10. (i guess it will be the same error with windows 8). Some white planes on screen arent recorded properly... (they apear black on the saved bitmap) I hope there will be an update to support new os soon

Comment: For those of you that are willing to use this software and trying to record multiple screens (or all in my case): At DesktopMirror::Load there is a PrimaryScreen.Width assignment. Changing this to the Lower and Upper Bounds (which you can find out by itterating through all screens) will allow you to cast all screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance, you should not be using GDI to read the desktop.

> ### [DWM: Performance Considerations and Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969536(v=vs.85).aspx)
>
> Avoid reading from or writing to a display DC. Although supported by DWM, we do not recommend it because of decreased performance.

and although you're not doing it, [some DirectDraw applications tried to lock the entire desktop window](http://www.virtualdub.org/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=149) to draw. In [Windows 7 applications that attempt that operation will fail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711(VS.85).aspx) - in addition to just being slow:

> **DirectDraw Lock**
>
> - **Windows 7**: Applications manifested for Windows 7 cannot call Lock API in DDRAW to lock the primary Desktop video buffer. Doing so will result in error, and **NULL** pointer for the primary will be returned. This behavior is enforced even if Desktop Window Manager Composition is not turned on. Windows 7 compatible applications must not lock the primary video buffer to render.
> - **Windows Vista (default):** Applications will be able to acquire a lock on the primary video buffer as legacy applications depend on this behavior. Running the application turns off Desktop Window Manager.