# Powershell: Write-Host is very slow

Tags: java, windows, powershell, screenshot

I have a Java application which has a functionality to take a screenshot. It does it by running Powershell script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing

$screens = [Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens

$top    = ($screens.Bounds.Top    | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
$left   = ($screens.Bounds.Left   | Measure-Object -Minimum).Minimum
$width  = ($screens.Bounds.Right  | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
$height = ($screens.Bounds.Bottom | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

$bounds   = [Drawing.Rectangle]::FromLTRB($left, $top, $width, $height)

$bmp      = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap ([int]$bounds.width), ([int]$bounds.height)

$graphics = [Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($bmp)

$graphics.CopyFromScreen($bounds.Location, [Drawing.Point]::Empty, $bounds.size)

$memStream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream

$bmp.Save($memStream, [Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Jpeg)

Write-Host $memStream.ToArray()

$graphics.Dispose()
$bmp.Dispose()
$memStream.Dispose()
```

Java application listens to the output of it and does some operations on it. The problem is that sometimes `Write-Host $memStream.ToArray()` takes too much time (Sometimes in 2 minutes, sometimes 3, or even 5). I'm not familiar with Powershell. Is there any analog of `Write-Host` which is faster? Or maybe I can take a screenshot using some other functionality faster? Thanks

Comment: It's likely going to be faster if you pass a single string to `Write-Host` instead of an array - try `Write-Host ([convert]::ToBase64String($memStream.ToArray()))` - of course you'll need to base64 decode the array in the java application but that's probably also faster than reifying the array by parsing the list you're currently getting :)

Comment: Is it `Write-Host` being slow or just `$memStream.ToArray()`? What happens when you instantiate it by e.g. assigning it to a variable: `$x = $memStream.ToArray()`?. I guess the command has a deferred execution and depending on the `CopyFromScreen` method, which indeed appears to have performance issues, see e.g.: [C# CopyFromScreen Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36411680/1701026)

Comment: @iRon Passing the b64 string to `Write-Host` instead of the underlying array gives me a ~40% increase in execution speed on a laptop with a single 1080p screen, the overhead from `Write-Host` having to construct a string representation is very real :)

Comment: For a slightly faster result, you can try instantiating the classes using the .Net method instead: `[System.IO.MemoryStream]::New()`. Also, (*maybe Mathias can shed some light on this*), but try saving the array to a variable first: `$Var = $memStream.ToArray()`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! I've tried `$Var = $memStream.ToArray()` and it took less than 1 second. One more questions Why is it better to do `Write-Host ([convert]::ToBase64String($memStream.ToArray()))` instead of `Write-Host $memStream.ToString()`

Comment: I understand one is `Base64String` and other one is just a `String`, I'm asking in performance wise

Comment: @Jakomo, the Base64 encoding reduces the size of the output string, which speeds things up, but I don't think that alone would be good enough. Are you saying your performance problem is solved by  doing `$var = $memStream.ToArray(); Write-Host $var` instead of `Write-Host $memStream.ToArray()`?

Comment: No Sorry, I just had `$var = $memStream.ToArray();` and it took 1 seconds without `Write-Host`

Comment: I tried using `$var = $memStream.ToArray(); Write-Host $var` but it didn't help, I still takes 5 min or so

Comment: Using `ToBase64String` Definitely speeded things up, It came down from 5 min to 1.5 minutes, is there any other optimization I can do?

Comment: @Jakomo why are you using PowerShell to take a screenshot from a Java application? Java can take screenshots natively. Either way the write-host perf suggests something else is going on. Can you offer any details around how you the powershell is executed?

Comment: @mklement0 I don't think the performance issue is expected here, even though logging a byte array to console is not a good serialization technique (base64 encoding is better but still takes a while it seems). I'm wondering how many displays at UHD resolutions they have which might make the array take longer to log each byte, and what the execution context here is. Either way the perf issue is with the serialization from PS and not the screencap so a Java native solution should eliminate the problem.

Comment: @mklement0 They are getting the dimensions of all attached screens and using that to get the screenshot. As written, unless I'm misreading something, this effectively captures the rendered content across all displays. As for this should only take 1 or 2 seconds, sure, for 1 or two HD displays or even a couple of UHD displays. But Windows supports a maximum of 16 of them. Display arrangement could bloat the final image size too. The potential is there for affecting perf here if we consider how large such a screenshot could be (though we don't actually know how large OP's screen area actually

Answer (score 1):

You stated a solution using other functionality would be acceptable, so why not perform the screen capture directly with the Java application instead? Java is fully capable of this natively:

```java
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

// Set up Robot and other vars
Robot robot = new Robot();
String imgFormat = "jpg";
BufferedImage screenBuffer;
Rectangle screenBounds;

// Enumerate all screens
GraphicsEnvironment graphEnv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] screens = graphEnv.getScreenDevices();

// Variables only used for generating filename
String fnameFormat = "%s-%s-screencap.%s";
String dtNowString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
String filename = String.format(fnameFormat, dtNowString, "all", imgFormat);

Rectangle allScreenBounds = new Rectangle();
int num = 0;
for(GraphicsDevice screen : screens) {
  screenBounds = screen.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
  allScreenBounds.x = Math.min(allScreenBounds.x, screenBounds.x);
  allScreenBounds.y = Math.min(allScreenBounds.y, screenBounds.y);

  // Make sure we only add extra pixels to the total width and height, subtracting overlapping dimensions
  // Does not take into account non-continuous display area, normally impossible on Windows
  allScreenBounds.width += Math.abs(allScreenBounds.width - (screenBounds.width + screenBounds.x));
  allScreenBounds.height += Math.abs(allScreenBounds.height - (screenBounds.height + screenBounds.y));

  System.out.println(String.format("Display %d: X=%d, Y=%d, Height=%d, Width=%d", num++, screenBounds.x, screenBounds.y, screenBounds.height, screenBounds.width));
}

System.out.println(String.format("Screen Area: X=%d, Y=%d, Height=%d, Width=%d", allScreenBounds.x, allScreenBounds.y, allScreenBounds.height, allScreenBounds.width));
screenBuffer = robot.createScreenCapture(allScreenBounds);

// Save the screencap to file
ImageIO.write(screenBuffer, imgFormat, new File(filename));
```

There is file-writing code there for testing but if this is performed by your application you can remove the filename variables, `import javax.imageio.ImageIO`, and the `ImageIO.write` call as you'll have the screenshot data in `screenBuffer` instead.